# how to hide button for specific user in opnerp

Tags: access-rights

I am creating access rights. I want to show one button for manager. don't show that button for user. how do i do it

```
<button name="%(crm.action_crm_lead2opportunity_partner)d" string="Convert to Opportunity" position="replace"/>
```

this code is using for hide that button. but It hides for both(manager and user). then  i try following code

```
<button name="%(crm.action_crm_lead2opportunity_partner)d" string="Convert to Opportunity" position="replace" groups="user"/>
```

I created user groups in openerp.

but following error come:

```
ValidateError

Error occurred while validating the field(s) arch: Invalid XML for View Architecture!
```

Answer (score 0):

If you created the access group in ir.model.access.csv in security folder or your using it 
from existing ACL here is how you should do it

manager_group
  user_group

-if you want to hide the button to user group it should be like this

```
  <button name="%(crm.action_crm_lead2opportunity_partner)d" string="Convert to Opportunity" position="replace" groups="manager_group"/>
```

- if you want to hide the button to manager or to any person make sure the manager group does not inherit access right from in the ir.model.access.csv file of other groups privileges